# Attach Sink to Overlapping Windows in StreamInsight

Tags: c#, system.reactive, streaminsight

I'm working on porting over some Reactive Extension queries to StreamInsight but have run into an issue with an overlapping window query.

I have a source setup in my StreamInsight server and I'm trying to write an overlapping window query like this:

```
var source = streamInsightServer.GetObservable<EventPattern<MyEventArg>>("EventSource");

var query = source.Window(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 250));
```

where source is `IQbservable<EventPattern<MyEventArg>>` and query is then `IQbservable<IObserverable<EventPattern<MyEventArg>>>`

With Reactive the observer was created as follows:

```
_observer = query.Subscribe(evts =>
            {
                evts.Count().Subscribe(c =>
                {
                    //push output here
                });
            });
```

How can I attach an observer to retrieve the equivalent output from StreamInsight?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've managed to create two sinks that achieve the same output as the Rx subscribtions as follows:

```
var query = source.Window(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250));
query.Deploy("windowQuery");
var innerSink = applicationStatus.DefineObserver(() => Observer.Create<int>(c => /*output here*/));
innerSink.Deploy("innerSink");
var sink = applicationStatus.DefineObserver(() => Observer.Create<IObservable<EventPattern<MyEventArg>>>(e => e.Count().AsQbservable().Bind(innerSink).Run().Void()));
sink.Deploy("mySink");
ProcessBinding = query.Bind(sink).Run("processBindingName");
```

To note though the `.Void()` method is simply an extension method that does nothing and returns void which causes the expression to be interpreted as an `Action` instead of a `Func` to match the required signature.  Also, all bindings created by running the inner sink are NOT disposed of and build up; these can be seen in the StreamInsight Event FLow Debugger.

While this achieves the same results I am not sure it qualifies as a good solution due to the extension method hack and not disposing of the inner process bindings. Still looking if anyone knows how to alternatively write this without these issues!

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to share a source of data, then you need to use `.With()`.

So your process should be:

```
var process = query.Bind(innerSink).With(query.Bind(sink).Run("processBindingName");
```

When you are done with the process or you want to shut down the application, you should just have to call `.Dispose()`.

As far as your windowing goes, you should use a HoppingWindow like this:

```
var query = from win in source.HoppingWindow(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 250))
select win.Count();
```

Comment: My goal isn't exactly to share a source of data; the Rx Window operator produces nested observables of IQbservable<IObservable<MyEventArg>. I can't use With because the observables for each sink are different, the inner sink observes integers. I've adapted the source to produce a point streamable and tried the SI HoppingWindow operator but it didn't produce the output as I was expecting; I think this because I'm not as familiar with SI and how application time advancement works.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really the way it works. The event payload classes provide schema in the StreamInsight engine. You'll need a separate sink for each payload type. The Bind() and With() methods allow you to bundle up query logic into a single process.